# Not receiving back a delivery_receipt_notification from GCM CCS

Tags: ios, go, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get a `receipt` from CCS, but I'm just not able to.

Here is what I'm doing:

I have a `go` script:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/brunohenrique/go-gcm/ccs"
)

var (
    user = struct {
        gcmToken string
    }{"mg0xe56LfjE:APA91bFHtHVQt85iNgyzTeDowovIGPAD_NbBjURppy1LgV9_oaM2R_9zn1fDXNuEeOoALTj7F8e8JmNPI3Md-CbbgTxdvxVrONFVfGz2dOujsaGkZjEhJcBH8sWvRNYZNIp2j2QliAEX"}
)


func main() {
    con := connect()


    // Sends a message
    con.Send(&ccs.OutMsg{
        To: user.gcmToken,
        ID: "m-1366082849205",
        Notification: map[string]interface{}{
            "title": "Hey!",
            "body": "There",
            "sound": "default",
        },
        TimeToLive: 600,
        DeliveryReceiptRequested: true,
        DelayWhileIdle: true,
    })


    // Listen to messages
    for {
        m, err := con.Receive()

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf(">>> Err: %+v \n", err)
        }

        go func(m *ccs.InMsg) {
            fmt.Printf(">>> InMsg: %+v \n", m)
        }(m)
    }
}
```

Everything seems alright when I run the script, but no receipt message back:

[image]

And this is what I'm doing when I get the notification:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Comment: Uh, hey, that token isn't supposed to secret...is it?

Comment: Don't think so, in order to send a notification to a device, you have to register it using your gcm user token :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for trying out GCM on iOS.
Unfortunately, delivery receipts are not available for display notifications on iOS at the moment.

Comment: Hi @TheWonderBird, thank you for your response. Would you mind letting us know where did you get this information from?

Comment: Hi @TheWonderBird, could you please point out in the documentation (or somewhere else) informations about that? I couldn't find anything about that and would love to have some references. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're trying this on Android or iOS, since it works for me on Android but it doesn't always work on iOS.

Delivery receipts for iOS do not work with the `notification` parameter in the request. I was able to get it to work for a plain `data` message i.e. with payload

```
{
  "to" : <reg id>,
  "data" : {
    "hello" : "world",
    "id" : 123
  }
}
```

But if I added the `notification` payload to the above one it didn't work.

I would assume that since a `notification` payload message needs to be sent via APNS there is no way for them to know whether the message was delivered or not since APNS does not return any result.

For a **no** `notification` message since it's received only when the app is in the foreground they would be able to verify if the message was delivered or not.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve that on iOS. I tried it here but it doesn't work. I'm trying to do that using a XMPP connection by the way.